# MVP Pattern in GWT: How to initialize Model/View and handle server requests in the Presenter?

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

This question isn't necessarily GWT bounded but on the other hand this comes right from my attempt to use it correctly.

I am using the MVP pattern (*as recommended*) in GWT but I am not sure how to deal with the model and the view as well as I am not quite sure how to create requests to the server. In particular I would like to know

- Where do I initialize `MyView`? Does the presenter do that by itself in the constructor or does it receive a valid reference as parameter to the constructor?
- The same with `MyModel`. As the instance of `MyModel` might be shared among different presenters I guess it should be passes to the presenters constructor.
- How do I make requests to the server in the presenter? Do I have an additional layer that will handle my request or is it recommended to use `MyServletAsync` right there as well?

I'm having a hard time figuring out a good design. See below an example code that shows how I am doing it now:

```
public class MyPresenter implements MyView.MyPresenter

    private final MyServletAsync myService = MyServlet.Util.getInstance();

    private MyModel myModel;
    private MyView myView;

    public MyPresenter(MyView myView, MyModel myModel) {

        this.myView = myView;
        this.myModel = myModel;

        // Register click handler ..

        this.myView.getNextXyzButton.addClickHandler(
            new ClickHandler() {
                @Override
                public onClick(Event event) {
                    requestXyz(this.myModel.getXyz().getOffset() + 1);
                }
            });

        this.myView.getPrevisousXyzButton.addClickHandler(
            new ClickHandler() {
                @Override
                public onClick(Event event) {
                    requestXyz(this.myModel.getXyz().getOffset() - 1);
                }
            });

        // Initialize Xyz with offset 0
        requestXyz(0);
    }

    /*
     * Should I do this here in the presenter or should I 
     * create another layer that handles requests?
     */
    private void requestXyz(final int byOffset) {
        myService.getXyzFromServer(byOffset, new AsyncCallback<XyzDto>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(XyzDto result) {
                updateModelWithResult(result);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                displayError(caught);
            }
        });
    }

    private updateModelWithResult(Xyz result) {     
        this.myModel.setXyz(result);
        this.myView.displayXyz(result);
    }

    private displayError(Throwable caught) {
        // ..
    }

}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: the mvp pattern is also described in the book "gwt in action". look at the example code in chapter 15 how to use mvp http://www.manning-source.com/books/tacy/gwtinaction2.zip It helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVP pattern is great, and it's designed to isolate but mediate totally different things. However, the pattern does not dictate how it's implemented and it's all on your own, but respecting some aspects, sure. Out of my experience, I would say that:

> Where do I initialize MyView?

A presenter is better to accept some kind of a view factory (or a supplier in general as we can already hold an existing view, especially in a GWT case), and let the presenter decide when instantiate or accept the view. My current project uses a small custom library that defines an abstract presenter and this is how it's implemented:

```java
public abstract class AbstractPresenter<M extends IModel, V extends IView>
        implements IPresenter<M, V> {

    private final M model;
    private final V view;

    protected AbstractPresenter(final M model, final IViewFactory<V, ? super IPresenter<M, V>> viewFactory) {
        this.model = model;
        view = viewFactory.createView(this);
    }

...

}
```

The main reason of passing the view factory is injecting the presenter to the view as views mostly should have references to their respective presenters (+ I prefer to have final fields, so this is a way of having both final references: presenter to view, and view to presenter).

> I guess it should be passes to the presenters constructor.

Yes, it may be passed via a constructor like in the example above, however some people may prefer set-accessors like `setModel` and `setView`.

> How do I make requests to the server in the presenter?

This is what model is for. A presenter is only a mediator between a model and a view, and it's basically only responsible for user interaction in both directions. Consider your model is a way to access your application, as a model should not be considered a dummy "get/set fields" object. Model is an abstraction over service layers, network communication (can be an abstraction behind a service), data storage, or whatever your application has. Thus, your presenter just has to notify the model for getting or putting some data (from/to elsewhere respectively). Also this allows you to write fully abstract layers. If you do unit testing, then you're in trouble for testing your presenter due to `private final MyServletAsync myService = MyServlet.Util.getInstance();` requiring the servlet to be up (a bad idea, right?). So if `getXyzFromServer` becomes a part of the model (I would say, then it might be named `getXyz` because the presenter does not really cares where the `Xyz` is fetched from), you can easily mock your model and just test the *pure* presenter.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I got the main parts of it but I still would like to know how the asynchronous calls would be handled in the model. If e.g. the presenter tells the model to perform an update on its data, then how would I notify the view to update itself? I would either need a reference to the presenter in the model or a callback for the presenter as the data arrives - to be honest I think it would be easier to handle those request in the presenter and then update the model and the view accordingly (maybe adding an additional service layer in front of the presenter).

Comment: Again, consider your model is an open gate to outer world, so the presenter would update view only being business-logic-free (assume the model received data from somewhere and updated itself). I would go for having the service layer behind the model. Let the presenter be aware of two objects only: model and view; and let your model not have a reference to the presenter (something like `M->[]`, `P->[M, V]`, `V->[P]`). This simplifies things very much. Your model *can* offer async methods that accept callbacks, and once your in-presenter callback is invoked, your presenter updates the view only.

Comment: It seems my problem is that until now I thought that the model should basically hold just the data and offer only getter/setter methods to my DAO objects. I was thinking about passing my DTOs to a service layer that returns valid DAO objects back to the presenter that sets/updates those in my model and tells the view to update itself as well. The model just can't offer functionality for all data it holds.

Comment: [Here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/todd_snyder/archive/2007/10/17/mvc-or-mvp-pattern-whats-the-difference.aspx) is a good image that shows that the model holds objects that them self have methods to to something with their data - but I never thought about letting some network communication happen there. Maybe I'm getting it still wrong or I have to sleep over this :D

Comment: Yep, you're getting it right. Network communication is an option. You can do whatever you want in your model. Simply speaking, the M is how the application business logic looks like from the perspective of P. In your question code, from what I understood, `MyServletAsync` is way much more a model than `MyModel` is. It was supposed to be just a get/set-driven data holder only, right?. If so, then there was no practical sense to have such a dummy object like `MyModel`. Just let it not to be a dummy data holder, but encapsulate `MyServletAsync` into it, and declare your model interface. That's it

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Just one more thing. Let's say I encapsulate `MyServletAsync` in `MyModel` for `MyPresener`, then `MyModel` would act like some kind of service layer, right? Would it make sense to create `Object1DAO`, Object2DAO`, etc. that represent the data and use `MyServletAsync` to fetch and store data from and to the server? Those object would be referenced in `MyModel` which offers then just the access to the P. My thought behind this is that I might not want to re-use the whole M in another view but maybe one of the DAO objects in another model. Would that make sense?

Comment: "then MyModel would act like some kind of service layer, right?" - Right, but just let call it Model, as we're talking about MVP and we don't care the its internals assuming that the Model interface is only thing we need. Yes, you can implement your DAO like that and back it with what's more appropriate for you.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help here! I think I'll give it a try. I was thinking about it the whole day and I guess it really does make sense to *not* let the presenter to any fetch or persist data stuff on the server for several reasons. Thanks! :)

Comment: "I might not want to re-use the whole M in another view but maybe one of the DAO objects in another model. Would that make sense?" - Yes, it does and that's the idea. I personally prefer not to re-use models, because they mostly don't fit any other presenter nicely. Again, just assume your models like something that lets your presenter to access _something_ via interface in MVP context just to update/interact with the view, so it does not need to have to know about the model internals, so your models can be implemented in any way (concrete objects, mocks, etc).

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. It's not easy getting my head around all this :D But I think I'm getting the picture by now.